# C++ using TABS spacing

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I am trying to make a `cout<<intRate<<"\t\t";` statement start out in different position then `cout <<"\t\t"<<monPayment;`.  My problem is aligning rate and payment values.

What I am getting for the output:

```
Principal            Interest Rate


   0.07    0.075   0.08    0.085   0.09    0.095   0.1
_______________________________________________________________
100000  665.302 699.215 733.765 768.913 804.623 840.854 877.572
________________________________________________________________
Interest rate is greater than .10 and the value is.105
```

I am trying to make it look like this:

```
Principal               Interest Rate


           0.07    0.075   0.08    0.085   0.09    0.095   0.1
_______________________________________________________________
100000  665.302 699.215 733.765 768.913 804.623 840.854 877.572
________________________________________________________________

Interest rate is greater than .10 and the value is .105
```

Where 0.07 is aligned with 665.302

Comment: People can help you more if you post some of your code.  Specifically, the parts that are relevant to generating your output.

Comment: Please show us what you've coded so far

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's difficult to tell from your question, but it sounds like you're looking for `iomanip`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main()
{
    std::cout << setw(4) << 1 << setw(4) << 2 << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
1   2
```

Comment: i try to run this but i got an error .. no such file or directory for <imanip> using codeblocks

Comment: @Joey Make sure you put `setw` in front of all your values, not just the first one.

Comment: setw(1); cout<<intRate<<"\t\t"; and setw(2);cout <<"\t\t"<<monPayment;?